# What does Eowen Cerise see in her last vision?

Tags: shannara

When **Wren Elessedil** is travelling back through Morrowindl in *"The Elfqueen of Shannara"* (book 3 of the Heritage series), **Eowen** has a vision of Wren shortly before she is lost to the Drakuls (and subsequently, is subverted by them):

> "In my vision, you stood alone atop a rise. It was clear that you were on Morrowindl. You held the Ruhk Staff and the Elfstones, but you could not use them. The others, those here, myself included, were black shadows cast upon the earth. Something approached you, huge and dangerous, yet you were not afraid - it was as if you welcomed it. Perhaps you did not realize that it threatened. There was a glint of bright silver, and you hastened to embrace it." ....
>
> "You must not do that, Wren. When it happens, remember."

What exactly does Eowen see? What was the danger she warned Wren about?

Comment: This is for *Heritage* series, right?  I think it's a premonition of her mute friend's fate, the one that began to change but asked for a Mercy Kill before that could happen.  I can't even remember names at the moment, so either someone else will snatch the answer, or I'll find it later once I have my sources again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most of Eowen's visions, she simply relays her understanding of what will happen.  This is the only time in the book she gives a visual of what she saw, and there's no scene in the books that matches it exactly, so the only interpretations that make sense are metaphorical.

Given that, **most of this appears to surround the events of Garth's death.**

> In my vision, you stood alone atop a rise. It was clear that you were on Morrowindl.

This is a fuzzier bit.  A rise is mentioned twice, once just before the Drakul, once again just before the Wisteron.  Neither rise was a significant place, just places where they gathered their wits before facing monsters.  Still on Morrowindl gives us a time limit; there's only so many chapters left where they're still on the island.  When Wren has her final conversation with Garth, it is in a clearing, but she is alone with him.

> You held the Ruhk Staff and the Elfstones, but you could not use them.

Every monster faced after this vision, including the Drakul that turn Eowen, are faced with the Elfstones magic.  The only time both are useless (and held, having just got the Ruhk Staff back) is in facing Garth after his poisoning from the battle with the Wisteron.

> The others, those here, myself included, were black shadows cast upon the earth.

This part most concerns Wren, because Eowen sees her death, but this implies everyone is dead.  By the time of Garth's death, the only companion left alive is Triss, other than the critters Faun and Stressa.  Possibly this can be interpreted as Triss dying if Wren makes the wrong choice concerning Garth, but it does make understanding fuzzier, again.

> Something approached you, huge and dangerous, yet you were not afraid - it was as if you welcomed it. Perhaps you did not realize that it threatened.

This is the most clear to me, because Garth has always been described as a giant of a Rover, and is the dearest and closest friend Wren has.  And the Wisteron's poison is slowly turning him into a Shadowen creature of some kind that will slaughter them all if Wren doesn't do as he asks.  If Wren cannot let go of Garth, they all die.

> There was a glint of bright silver, and you hastened to embrace it.

Garth's knife is described as glinting as he hands it to her, asking Wren to kill him before he can turn.

Other interpretations are possible (an argument can be made that this is referring to when the Drakul nearly put her in thrall), but Wren needing to mercy kill Garth appears to fit the most elements.